# Managing large number of target preprocessor macros in iOS XCode project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

My app has numerous targets in it, and each target specifies a large amount of preprocessor macros used by the projects. They're anywhere from switches to definitions of strings and URLs. I'm starting to have trouble managing such a large number of them sanely through the xcode Build Settings UI and was wondering what people with larger multi-target projects would recommend I do to alleviate the pain.

One solution would be to define a single switch in each target and then dump all of the definitions into -Prefix.pch file, essentially having the same effect as if I defined those macros in the build settings.

Another solution would be to have a module handling configuration (could be a wrapper for a plist) and bundle a different plist with the same filename into each target. This way I could have a nice well-defined interface for accessing the different settings with the bonus of being able to add some logic in there.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

All of my projects include a `Constants.h` file that takes care of string definitions, various flags, image names, etc., and preprocessor macros. I just include `Constants.h` in pretty much every class I create.

I also have several targets in some apps to control UI themes and web service calls, amongst other things, so I do the following in `Constants.h`:

```
#ifdef APPLE
#define IMAGE_LOGO "apple.png"
#endif

#ifdef MICROSOFT
#define IMAGE_LOGO "windows.png"
#endif

#ifdef LINUX
#define IMAGE_LOGO "penguin.png"
#endif

//etc...
```

I'm not sure if it's ideal, but this works perfectly for my needs and you don't have to mess around with the annoying Build Settings UI except to set the flag on each target (E.g., `APPLE=1`). Hope it helps.

Comment: You can even avoid that last part.  Each target probably has its own PCH file, so you could `#define APPLE` in there.  I actually never knew you could do it in the build settings until last week, and I've been doing a multi-target project for over 6 months now :p.